# RTEMS libbsd compilation issue

Tags: rtems

I followed the steps mentioned in the link 
https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems-libbsd
for sparc and 4.12 version.

```
# cd /opt
# mkdir RTEMS
# cd RTEMS

# sandbox="$PWD/sandbox"
# mkdir sandbox
# cd "$sandbox"
# git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder.git
# git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems.git
# git clone git://git.rtems.org/rtems-libbsd.git

Build and install the tools.
# cd rtems-source-builder/rtems
# ../source-builder/sb-set-builder --prefix="$sandbox/rtems-4.12" 4.12/rtems-sparc

Bootstrap the RTEMS sources:
-----------------------------
# cd "$sandbox"
# cd rtems
# PATH="$sandbox/rtems-4.12/bin:$PATH"
# ./bootstrap

# cd "$sandbox" or cd ..
# mkdir b-sis
# cd b-sis
# "$sandbox/rtems/configure" --target=sparc-rtems4.12 --prefix="$sandbox/rtems-4.12" --disable-networking --enable-tests=samples --enable-rtemsbsp=sis
# make
# make install

Build and install rtems-libbsd
================================

# cd "$sandbox"
# cd rtems-libbsd
# git submodule init
# git submodule update rtems_waf
# waf configure --prefix="$sandbox/rtems-4.12" --rtems-bsps=sparc/sis
```

In this step I got an error

```
Setting top to                           : /home/subhilash/RTEMS/sandbox/rtems-libbsd 
Setting out to                           : /home/subhilash/RTEMS/sandbox/rtems-libbsd/build 
No valid arch/bsps found
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means waf configure was unable to find sparc/sis installed in your prefix. Probably, configure and make failed without an obvious error due to the removal of the sis BSP from RTEMS during the 4.12 development cycle. Try using erc32 instead of sis.

You may get timelier responses about RTEMS by inquiring on the users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be aware that the sis simulator for the erc32 does not have a simulated NIC. And as I right this, the greth driver that you probably want for LEON CPUs doesn't yet have a driver in the rtems-libbsd TCP/IP stack. It is supported by the legacy IPV4 stack.

We would welcome a contribution to port this driver to the new stack.

I don't know if the greth driver is supported by qemu but the basic leon3 is supported.